# Дайте фидбек коду

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, инспекция-кода, чистый-код

Всем привет, я сделал свой учебный проект, но хочу узнать мнение и свои ошибки у более опытных разработчиков. Проект основан на ASP.NET CORE и Angular. Сделал что-то подобное на сайты UP-X и т.д, то есть, у меня должно выйти обычное мини-казино. В ходе разработки, у меня возникли некоторые вопросы, но вот главный:

1. Где лучше писать логику с БД и проверками, ибо читал мнение, что весь код должен быть в сервисе, а в контроллере одна +- строка. Но как быть тогда с конструкторами? Допустим, у меня есть контроллер и у него есть конструктор. У меня есть class, где есть тоже конструктор(Bankcard и PaymentsService), который я делаю в сервисе. Плодить инициализацию в контроллере и сервисе, которая будет одинаковая - как-то не очень, я так думаю. К тому же, как тогда добавить в DI все это. Пример того, что я имею ввиду(PaymentsService):

   ```
   private readonly BankCard _bankCard = new BankCard(); 

    //переделать в это:

        private readonly BankCard _bankCard;

        public PaymentsService(BankCard bankCard)
        {
            _bankCard = bankCard;
        }
   ```

Но тогда нужно передать в контроллере, где будет конструктор PaymentsService что-то, если буду там инициализировать его.

Делать так, если я не ошибаюсь, то это не очень-то правильно:

```
private readonly BankCard _bankCard = new BankCard();
```

Github: https://github.com/Hich1k/UpX

Меня больше интересует back, но если кто-то может посмотреть front, то я буду только рад.

Спасибо заранее всем, кто хоть немного уделил внимание этому ужасному коду, ибо для меня важно знать, где я делаю ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте IoC контейнер, тогда вариант останется только один, и вопрос отпадет сам собой.

Код глянул, `BankCard` - странное название. Вообще банковская карта это всего-лишь контейнер платежных реквизитов (которые передаются только в защищенном поле платежных сервисов и недоступны вашему серверу), а у вас это класс, в котором происходит списание денег с аккаунта, при чем это скорее всего вообще синглтон должен быть, судя по логике. Такое название класса сбивает с толку и затрудняет формирование ответа на данный вопрос. Назовите его `PaymentInvoker` или как-то так и зарегистрируйте как синглтон в IoC контейнере. Получайте через конструктор, через инициализацию поля такая история синтаксически уже просто не прокатит.

А технически оба предложенных варианта идентичны, разница только в написании.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ. По вашему мнению, на какой уровень я тяну с этим кодом? Думаю попробовать найти работу с данным проектом, но не знаю, насколько он подходит хотя бы на уровень джуна.

Comment: @Hich1k А я? Я вообще даже джуном никогда не был и программистом не работал, поэтому вряд-ли могу что-то вменяемое насоветовать. Код на уровне ученика неплох, но видны дыры в понимании того что вы пишете. "Как-то оно работает" - это не понимание. Следует осознавать архитектуру приложения и иметь четкий ответ на вопрос, а почему она такая, а не какая-то другая. Вот тогда до джуна будет как рукой подать. Но и джуны разные бывают, так что могу промахнуться в рассуждениях. Шаблоны проектирования разные поизучайте, добавит понимания.